# Can't delete time machine backups - error 8072

Tags: backup, trash, macos, time

I am not able to delete permanently time machine backups from an external hard drive which are now in my trash. After an hour or so « deleting items » and a growing number, I get « the operation can’t be completed because an unexpected error occurred error code -8072 ». I have tried many times and different backups but no success.
I can’t even restore them out of the trash anymore and have therefore not managed to free any space from my hard drive which was the aim.

Here is what I have done :
-deleted some backups directly via finder
-stopped auto backups from time machine to avoid interference
-tried emptying the trash or « delete immediately » individually

Any help would be appreciated, have tried looking around but no luck so far.

MacBook Air (13-inch mid 2011)
macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, because of how Apple has secured the system files, you'll have to erase/reformat the external hard drive (using disk utility or similar apps).

Otherwise, it will *literally* never delete. I've tried doing the same thing with terminal and finder, and apple won't delete the files.